# os.OpenFile permission problems in test

Tags: go

I'm currently having a problem with os.OpenFile. It just gives me "permission denied" when i run my go test.

```
type log struct {
    Message   string
    Source    string
    Timestamp time.Time
    ErrorCode ErrorCode
}

type ErrorCode int

const (
    Info ErrorCode = 1 + iota
    Warning
    Error
)

func (errorCode ErrorCode) String() string {
    switch errorCode {
    case Info:
            return "Info"
    case Warning:
            return "Warning"
    case Error:
            return "Error"
    }
    return "Type not found"
}

func writeToLog(logItem log) {
    err := os.Chdir("..")
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can't change working directory")
    }
    err = os.Mkdir("logs", os.FileMode(0777))
    if err != nil && os.IsNotExist(err) {
            fmt.Println("Can't create log directory")
    }
    f, err := os.OpenFile("logs/log.txt",
            os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, os.FileMode(0666))
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Can't find logfile")
            fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Sync()
    defer f.Close()

    f.WriteString(logItem.ErrorCode.String() + logItem.Source +
            logItem.Message + logItem.Timestamp.String())
}
```

Output:

```
Can't find logfile
open logs/log.txt: permission denied
Can't find logfile
open logs/log.txt: permission denied
```

What am I doint wrong? It seems like OpenFile doesn't set my permissions correctly (-rw-r--r--).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can run your code without issue in my environment. I don't think this is a programming problem. Can you create a log.txt file in the logs directory outside of your program?

Comment: The problem was in ChDir, which was called everytime and changed the directory over and over again, much further in the tree than only `..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve this problem.

```
os.Chdir("..")
```

was called over and over again. And obviously the current working directory is stored and doesn't change back to what it was after the func was done.

After removing it, everything worked perfectly normal. I just added the `../` to the `os.Mkdir` and to `os.OpenFile`.

I'm looking to work with environment variables to makes this work better I think.